# Jquery works only on first page load (ajax paganation)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Only problem:** jquery won't trigger the click event of my anchor link for rest of the ajax loaded pages except on first page.

*There are already many answers found with this topic but none of them works for me.*

**Things Ive tried:** *(pls take a look..I might implement it in the wrong way)*

**1.)** Wrapping with `div data-role="page"` first before the click event:

```
 $('a[id^="preview"]').wrap('<div data-role="page" />');
 //... click event code.. see below
```

**2.)** Using the `body` to capture event on specified link

```
$('body').on('click','a[id^="preview"]',function(e) {
//... click event code.. see below
```

**3.)** Tried putting the script on head or in body.

**4.)** Tried putting the the script externally or within body.

All of the things I've tried fails. Just working on the 1st page.

---

Here's my code for the click event and works perfectly on first load (1st page):

```
$('a[id^="preview"]').on('click',function(e) {   
        alert('preview clicked');
 });
```

**Note:**

I'm using `$('a[id^="preview"]')` because the link are dynamically created with number suffix. e.g. preview1, preview2...etc.

Comment: did you forget to include jquery? are you getting any error in console of the browser?

Comment: no errors in ff and chrome. Yes I did include jquery (#3 (Things Ive Tried)).

Comment: Can you show how the ajax pagination is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify your example and add this code to see if that works if it does expand fromt here.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hpaL/

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('body').append('<br><a href="#">Click me<a/>')
});

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
alert('It works!');
});
```

Comment: yes I already did.. but bind and live were deprecated right? im using the latest jquery.

Comment: I already tried that (#2 above). Still works on 1st page.. Will try to expand it later. thanks

Comment: Are you preventing click events from bubbling up to body, either with e.stopPropagation() or return false?

Comment: @ty. yes applied it too. My main issue is when I move to the next page and all the event functionality are gone (I mean still there but not executed) without any error on browser.

Comment: My feeling is your problem is not in the click propagation but the selector or ajax. Do you have live demo?

Comment: Is your first page Ajax loaded or static?

Comment: @miro Yes my Ajax is loaded. wait will try to create simple jsfiddle just to show simple pagination. The rest of the elements structure and selectors on the example code are on the same structure with my development.

Comment: As an alternitive you can always try <a onclick='myfunction()'> and then myfunction will get called regardless of when or how the element was added to the DOM.