# Jquery : function to catch actual element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is seemed to be related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397777/jquery-works-only-on-first-page-load-ajax-paganation) but my purpose here is:

**Purpose:** to troubleshoot and detect actual dom element being clicked.

This is just my simplest way of accessing id/class of the element clicked.

```
$("span").on('click', function(event) {   
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("The span element was clicked. ID:" + $(this).attr("id") + " ; Class=" + $(this).attr("class"));
  });

  $("p").on('click', function(event) {   
     event.stopPropagation();
    alert("The p element was clicked. ID:" + $(this).attr("id") + " ; Class=" + $(this).attr("class"));
  });

  $("div").on('click', function(event) {   
     event.stopPropagation();
    alert("The div element was clicked. ID:" + $(this).attr("id") + " ; Class=" + $(this).attr("class"));
  });

    $("tr").on('click', function(event) {   
     event.stopPropagation();
    alert("The tr element was clicked. ID:" + $(this).attr("id") + " ; Class=" + $(this).attr("class"));
  });

$("a").on('click', function(event) {   
     event.stopPropagation();
    alert("The a element was clicked. ID:" + $(this).attr("id") + " ; Class=" + $(this).attr("class"));
  });
```

Hopefully someone can **improve** my code in a single function or something.

*Though I can see how elements are structured on chrome and ffox but I'm still wondering why I can't catch the event on element tag with specified ID.*

```
$('a[id^="preview"]').on('click',function(e) {
     alert($(this).attr("id"));

 });
```

**Additional info:** I wrap the whole table with `DIV` and all `A` with span

Question in mind to solve: *What is clicked then if my Click event handler didn't work? (might be something else...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick this in one call..

```
    $("span, a, p, div, tr").on('click', function(event) {   
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $this = $(this);
        alert("The " + $this.prop("tagName") + " element was clicked. ID:" + 
               $this.prop("id") + " ; Class=" + $this.prop("class"));
      });
```

Comment: Alternatively you could cache the jquery object instead of repeatedly calling it with $(this) using `var $this = $(event.target);` or `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: In jQuery, event.target always holds the DOM element that is the source of the event. It's the simplest way I think.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the object caching.